# ¿Cómo recorro un json que tiene varios items con un for en vb?

Tags: json, vb.net

Quiero recorrer el Json que recibo por la api con un For ya que tengo varios Pedidos pero solo me sale el total de pedidos
Y necesito entrar en cada uno de sus detalles por separado para agregarlos en la base de datos

```
Dim m2 = New Class_Magento_Saint(UrlSitioWeb)
    Dim token = m2.GetAdminToken().Trim(""""c)
    Dim client = New RestClient With {.BaseUrl = New Uri(UrlSitioWeb)}
    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
    Dim Pedidos As New Ordenes()
    Dim Items As New List(Of Item)()

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & token)
    request.Resource = Url_api3
    Dim response = client.Execute(request)

    If response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim product As Ordenes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Ordenes)(response.Content)

        Dim nue = product.Items

        For Each item In product.Items

        Next
```

[image: Para Entrar en cada uno de sus propiedades]